# can we use goto statement within the switch statement? in php

Tags: php, switch-statement, fatal-error, break, goto

i m new to php and coding is old school

```
<?php
  for($i=-2; $i<count($s2)-1;$i++){ ?>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <?php
    switch ($i) {
       case '-2':       
        echo "JR KG";  
        goto a;        
        break;

        case '-1':
        echo "SR KG";
        break;

        case '0':
        echo "Nursery";
        break;

        default:
        echo $i;
    ?>
    </td>
    <?php foreach($a2 as $aaa){  a: ?>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $aaa.'['.$i.']'; ?>" >
    </td>
    <?php
       }
    ?>                              
</tr>
<?php
   }
}
?>
```

by above code i wanted to display list of standard and display a checkbox for each division (a-h). after printing standard i want to display the grid like checkboxs. this works for i= 1 to 12.. fails for -2,-1,0 because of break();

so i tried adding a goto a; but getting following error

**Fatal error: 'goto' into loop or switch statement is disallowed in**

any suggestions how to get the checkboxes for each division for the 1st three fields.

with the loop of "i" i am starting a row that display standard, and with the loop of "foreach($a2)" i am want to append number of checkboxes foreach divison in $a2.. want to create like a grid.  its failing to append the checkboxes in first 3 rows because of break()

thanks.

Comment: **DONT USE GOTO** Where have you been since the 70's man!

Comment: i also tried if($i == -2){ echo "sr kg"; goto a; }  but still same fatal error..  pls guide what else shall i try

Comment: But just out of interest where is the label **a:**

Comment: in the start of foreach($a2 as $aaa){ a:

Comment: Well for a start I doubt if you can jump to a label that you generate at runtime? Not even in **old school programming** The label has to be there at compile time, or interpretation time in PHP's case. It labels a momory address in your code segment

Comment: I would but I dont understand what you are trying to do. Please edit the question, and explain exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: just move the a: label behind the foreach, not inside it :p

Comment: @hanshenrik please check the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php). There are pictures for the hard of hearing!

Comment: ^obviously never coded in assembly nor visual basic Edit: @RiggsFolly originally said "for every language"-something. he later edited it.

Comment: @hanshenrik Actually I have coded in both those languages. Assembler was on a big iron mainframe back when programming was considered a science rather than a pastime.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with using goto **from** a switch statement. The problem is with using goto **to** a foreach block.

Comment: Yeah thanks for pointing that out.. my target point should have been before foreach... However those were my just starting days and didn't have much idea in php

Answer (score 1):

You can use a goto within a Switch statement.

However, you cannot jump to a label within a foreach loop because the foreach variables will have not been instantiated.  In your code, if you were to jump to the label inside the foreach loop, your $aaa variable would not have been defined.  The foreach pointer has never been initiated.

If PHP were to allow jumping into a foreach statement, the code will almost always yield unpredictable results.

Answer (score 0):

I am still no totally sure I understand.

But if you want to do something different in the three special cases try this general idea.

```
<?php
function add_checkboxes($i, $a2) {
    // do the checkbox processing in here
    if ( $i == -2 ) {
        foreach($a2 as $aaa){  a: ?>
           echo '<td>';
           echo  '<input type="checkbox" name="' . $aaa . '['.$i.'] .'" >';
           echo '</td>';
        }
    }
}


for($i=-2; $i<count($s2)-1;$i++){ 
?>
  <tr>
    <td>
<?php
    switch ($i) {
        case '-2':       
            echo "JR KG";  
            add_checkboxes($i, $a2);
            break;

        case '-1':
            echo "SR KG";
            add_checkboxes($i, $a2);
            break;

        case '0':
        echo "Nursery";
            add_checkboxes($i, $a2);
            break;

        default:
            echo $i;
?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
   }
}
?>
```